# How to get a piece of identifiable data when writing to an AWS SQS Queue?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've got an app that needs to track the transaction id (or something similar) of a message sent to an SQS queue.

If I send with the following class, how could I get some piece of identifiable data with querying the queue?

```
@Component
public class SqsQueueDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqsQueueDao.class);
    private final QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("awsClient")
    AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSQSAsyncClient;

    public SqsQueueDao(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsyncClient) {
        this.queueMessagingTemplate = new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsyncClient);
    }

    //TODO: implement a strategy for identifying the message id
    public Long send(String queueName, String message) {
        queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
        //return some long identifying data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQS assigns a message ID, but the `queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend` method doesn't return anything. If you send the message using the SQS client directly then you would get a `SendMessageResult` object that would have the message ID on it. However the SQS message ID Is a `String` not a number, so you still wouldn't be able to fulfill your contract to return a `Long`.

If you can return a `String` message ID instead of a `Long`, then the code would look like this:

```
public String send(String queueName, String message) {
    // Could probably cache this URL instead of looking up each time
    String queueUrl = amazonSQSAsyncClient.getQueueUrl(queueName).getQueueUrl();

    SendMessageResult result = amazonSQSAsyncClient.sendMessage(queueUrl, message);
    return result.getMessageId();
}
```